# do I need to put scatter-gather DMA linked list to none-cacheable memory?

Tags: c

all source and destination are in none-cacheable  memory.  there is no question there.
before I start DMA(, which is scatter-gather DMA), I compose the DMA linked list (with src,dest, size and next).  I think I do not have to put the list in the none-cacheable memory.  Can somebody confirm that?
thanks very much in advance!
linda

Comment: What OS?  What kind of CPU?  Your question is rather incoherent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is that anything that is modified by the hardware directly, needs to be in non-cacheable memory. Otherwise, as you can imagine, the code running on the CPU may see stale data from it's caches. So, the buffers, *and any other data structures* directly modified by the hardware need to be marked non-cacheable. If the hardware is manipulating the list in any way, or updating any status bits etc., then that needs to be non-cacheable too.

> all source and destination are in none-cacheable memory. there is no question there

BTW, this assertion does not always hold. If the hardware implements other cache coherence mechanisms (bus snooping etc.), then you don't need to worry about even the buffers.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer.  in my case, the linked list is modified only by s/w and it is modified before I start DMA.  in that case, is it ok to put the linked list in none-cacheable memroy?

Comment: Yes, in that case, it can be in either kind of memory. Don't forget to accept an answer that helps you.

Comment: sorry. I am very new here.  how do I accept.  click the "green check"?your answer is very helpful!!